# Is the window size in ksqlDB configurable after creation of the query?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am working on a use case where I am checking the number of salary raises an employee has for a particular time frame. I wanted the time frame that is the window size to be configurable at a later stage when the need arises. For example, for the following query:

```html
create table salary_hike_frequency as select 
   empID, count(*) as cnt,
   latest_by_offset(name->first_name) as name, 
   latest_by_offset(salary->base_salary) as salary
   from emp_salary 
   window tumbling (size 180 days)
   group by empID having count(*) > 2
   emit changes;
```

If I now want to update the query ( basically change the window size ) to

```html
create table salary_hike_frequency as select 
       empID, count(*) as cnt,
       latest_by_offset(name->first_name) as name, 
       latest_by_offset(salary->base_salary) as salary
       from emp_salary 
       window tumbling (size 30 days)
       group by empID having count(*) > 2
       emit changes;
```

I get the following error

Cannot add table 'salary_hike_frequency': A table with the same name already exists

Now I don't want to create another topic for the updated window size. The only workaround I found was to terminate the query, drop the table and then run the query with the updated window size again. This then adds data to the same topic 'salary_hike_frequency', although starting from the beginning of the 'emp_salary' topic. ( I have set 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest')

However, this process seems very hacky and neither using [variables](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/define/) as parameters for the window worked nor using [in-place upgrades](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/update-a-running-persistent-query/). Both gave the following errors respectively (for reference only):-

```html
-- the queries using variables
ksql> define windowsize = '30';
ksql> create table salary_hike_frequency as select
>   empID, count(*) as cnt,
>   latest_by_offset(name->first_name) as name, 
>   latest_by_offset(salary->base_salary) as salary
>   from emp_salary 
>   window tumbling (size ${windowsize} days)
>   group by empID having count(*) > 2
>   emit changes;

-- the error
line 6:26: mismatched input '${windowsize}' expecting {'-', INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, FLOATING_POINT_VALUE}
Statement: create table salary_hike_frequency as select 
   empID, count(*) as cnt,
   latest_by_offset(name->first_name) as name, 
   latest_by_offset(salary->base_salary) as salary
   from emp_salary 
   window tumbling (size ${windowsize} days)
   group by empID having count(*) > 2
   emit changes;
Caused by: line 6:26: mismatched input '${windowsize}' expecting {'-', INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, FLOATING_POINT_VALUE}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

and

```html
-- the query trying for in-place upgrades
create or replace table salary_hike_emp as 
>   select empID, count(*) as cnt,
>   latest_by_offset(name->first_name) as name, 
>   latest_by_offset(salary->base_salary) as salary
>   from emp_salary 
>   window tumbling (size 30 days)
>   group by empID having count(*) > 2
>   emit changes;

-- the error
Cannot upgrade data source: DataSource '`SALARY_HIKE_EMP`' has topic = KsqlTopic{kafkaTopicName='SALARY_HIKE_EMP',keyFormat=KeyFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=KAFKA, properties={}}, features=[], window=Optional[WindowInfo{type=TUMBLING, size=Optional[15552000000]}]}, valueFormat=ValueFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=AVRO, properties={}}, features=[]}} which is not upgradeable to KsqlTopic{kafkaTopicName='SALARY_HIKE_EMP',keyFormat=KeyFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=KAFKA, properties={}}, features=[], window=Optional[WindowInfo{type=TUMBLING, size=Optional[2592000000]}]}, valueFormat=ValueFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=AVRO, properties={}}, features=[]}}
```

I wanted to know if there was any other way of tackling this problem other than replacing upgrades?

I am using the confluent platform 6.1.0 through the docker-compose file for my cluster. No. of Partition for the above topics is 1 as well as the replication factor, any other values are default.

Comment: This question was answered here https://confluentcommunity.slack.com/archives/C6UJNMY67/p1617344668282900